# Mount CD/DVD in GRUB

Tags: grub2

How to access CD's content in GRUB, when booted from HDD?

This is what I would like to do:

```
title Boot from CD with modified parameters
        root (cd)
        kernel /live/vmlinuz <my parameters>
        initrd /live/initrd.img
```

or

```
title Boot from CD with my parameters
        kernel (cd)/live/vmlinuz <my parameters>
        initrd (cd)/live/initrd.img
```

Except, when the GRUB is loaded from HDD, there is no (cd) device.

I would like to boot from Live CD, but using different kernel boot parameters than those specified in ISOLINUX config file present on the CD. I don't want to rewrite it each time I boot. I thought I would just boot using HDD/UFD, then let GRUB load the kernel and initrd from the CD.

Is this somehow possible?

Comment: Can you try and explain this a bit more? It's extremely confusing what you're attempting to do.

Comment: I rewrote the question